# Select text box on page load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which uses JavaScript to select a text box when the page loads. I have included a copy of my code below. My question is how can this be done in jQuery?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<input id="query">

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function box(query){
         document.getElementById('query').focus();
      }
      box('query');
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, Callum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#query').focus()
});
```

Answer (score 16):

You also can use HTML5:

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_button_autofocus.asp

Cross Browser Compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus

Comment: I prefer this way if you just need a simple focus. It produces better performance although this one doesn't relate to his question

Comment: jep, but it was only an suggestion :)

Comment: My question is why would somebody want to do this in jQuery :?

Comment: @Darkyen You'll need to do this with jQuery when you have to support IE < 10 and for me (as well as most people in advertising) that is on every project...

Comment: The top answer is correct because it answers the user, but I agree with everyone else that this answer is the cleanest and sexiest answer to the question.